# Restarting a method

Tags: c#, methods, resources

I am making a C# aplication. I have got one main process for verifying data from a database. A timer checks every 100 ticks if I have user input. After I get user input my main process continues (it waits for userinput at the start). After verifying and doing multiple things the method is done. The thing is, I would like it to go to the beginning again waiting for the next bit of input.

I was thinking of calling the method again at every possible end of the process. I have a feeling that this will create a resource heavy program though (not the worst thing, but better no bad habits than a few right?).

Example:

```
bool cont = false;

public void process() 
{    
    while (cont == false) {;}

    //Various sorting criteria that all end up with cont = false; process(), the userinput has been processed.

}

timer1 tick event 
{
    if (userinput) 
        cont = true;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the question here?

Comment: My bad. I was wondering if there are any proper ways of getting a method to it's start again. I felt my way (keep calling the Method) would be very resource heavy.

Comment: you can use recursion

Comment: Can you share your code? I'm having a tough time picturing how it's structured / written currently.

Comment: I have added example code. It seems to be recursion. I'll look into that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As you don't saw how you will get the user input, i don't implemented this one. But the main logic to your question is :

```
class MainClass
{ 
    public static void Main()
    {
        MyRecursiveFunction();
        AfterUserInput();
    }

    public static void MyRecursiveFunction()
    {
        if (userinput)
        { return; }

        // Waits 100 ticks to check again
        Thread.Sleep(new TimeSpan(100));

        MyRecursiveFunction();
    }

    public static void AfterUserInput()
    {
        // All that you need to do after the user input
    }
}
```